# How to handle Cancel button on the dialog shown by NetworkRequest.Builder().setNetworkSpecifier

Tags: android, networking, android-networking

I'm trying to connect to WiFi AP provided by peripheral device with NetworkRequest.Builder().setNetworkSpecifier().
I succeeded to connect but I still have a problem in failure case.

```
   fun connectPeerWifiNetworkFlow(peerSpecifier: NetworkSpecifier) = callbackFlow {
        val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(peerSpecifier)
            .build()

        val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                super.onAvailable(network)
                trySend(network)
            }

            override fun onUnavailable() {
                super.onUnavailable()
                trySend(null)
            }
        }
        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback)
        awaitClose {
            connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
        }
    }
```

This code worked fine but I had a problem when no AP was found.
A result dialog will be shown if no AP has not been found.
Any callback wasn't called even if "Cancel" button was tapped on the dialog.
How can I handle "Cancel" behavior?

[Dialog shown when no AP was found][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0W1e.png**strong text**